# I think I've broken ajax somehow... but can't fix it

Tags: php, ajax, centos, plesk

I'm using ScriptCase on a Centos / Plesk VPS. I had been having error messages about updates not working due to transaction errors and tracked it down to a bug in the MySQL 5.5 libraries and followed the MySQL bug fix which then allowed yum update to do its thing. It has upgraded to MySql 5.6 as part of that. It ran through about 430 updates overall.

Since then my webpages have broken. They have gone from:
[image: working screen]

to:

[image: broken screen]

Looking at the (extensive) source code generated by ScriptCase it relies heavily on Ajax - so I'm guessing that Ajax isn't working properly.

I can't find any suggestions so far as to what might have broken or how to resurrect it.

I've included the first part of the code for the page but not the entire thing because it was very long.

Help on how to fix this would be appreciated!

```html
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

<html DIR='LTR'>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>DutyDoctor Rota System: Login </TITLE>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <META http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT" />
  <META http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Thu, 20 Jul 2017 10:21:02 GMT" />
  <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />
  <META http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
  <META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_lib/prod/third/jquery_plugin/thickbox/thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    var sc_pathToTB = '/_lib/prod/third/jquery_plugin/thickbox/';
    var sc_blockCol = 'scriptcase__NM__btn__NM__scriptcase8_DarkBlue__NM__tree_menos.png';
    var sc_blockExp = 'scriptcase__NM__btn__NM__scriptcase8_DarkBlue__NM__tree_mais.png';
    var sc_ajaxBg = '#6e6e6e';
    var sc_ajaxBordC = '#8DA0C8 ';
    var sc_ajaxBordS = 'solid';
    var sc_ajaxBordW = '1px';
    var sc_ajaxMsgTime = 2;
    var sc_img_status_ok = '/_lib/img/scriptcase__NM__iconsuccess.png';
    var sc_img_status_err = '/_lib/img/scriptcase__NM__iconfails.png';
    var sc_css_status = 'scFormInputError';
  </SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/prod/third/jquery/js/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/prod/third/jquery/js/jquery-ui.js"></SCRIPT>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_lib/prod/third/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/lib/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/lib/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/prod/third/jquery_plugin/malsup-blockui/jquery.blockUI.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/prod/third/jquery_plugin/thickbox/thickbox-compressed.js"></SCRIPT>
  <style type="text/css">
    .fileinput-button-padding {
      padding: 3px 10px !important;
    }
    
    .fileinput-button {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 4px;
    }
    
    .fileinput-button input {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: solid transparent;
      border-width: 0 0 100px 200px;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      -moz-transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);
      direction: ltr;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/lib/js/jquery.scInput.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/lib/js/jquery.fieldSelection.js"></SCRIPT>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_lib/css/Sc8_PictonBlue/Sc8_PictonBlue_form.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_lib/css/Sc8_PictonBlue/Sc8_PictonBlue_formLTR.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_lib/css/Sc8_PictonBlue/Sc8_PictonBlue_tab.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_lib/css/Sc8_PictonBlue/Sc8_PictonBlue_tabLTR.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_lib/buttons/scriptcase8_DarkBlue/scriptcase8_DarkBlue.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login/login_ltr.css" />

  <script>
    var scFocusFirstErrorField = false;
    var scFocusFirstErrorName = "";
  </script>


  <form name="form_ajax_redir_1" method="post" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" name="nmgp_parms">
    <input type="hidden" name="nmgp_outra_jan">
    <input type="hidden" name="script_case_session" value="aud3rabup6ud7kpmgr0l87inq7">
  </form>
  <form name="form_ajax_redir_2" method="post" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" name="nmgp_parms">
    <input type="hidden" name="nmgp_url_saida">
    <input type="hidden" name="script_case_init">
    <input type="hidden" name="script_case_session" value="aud3rabup6ud7kpmgr0l87inq7">
  </form>

  <SCRIPT>
    // remote scripting library
    // (c) copyright 2005 modernmethod, inc
    var sajax_debug_mode = false;
    var sajax_request_type = "POST";
    var sajax_target_id = "";
    var sajax_failure_redirect = "";

    function sajax_debug(text) {
      if (sajax_debug_mode)
        alert(text);
    }

    function sajax_init_object() {
      sajax_debug("sajax_init_object() called..")

      var A;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        A = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        var msxmlhttp = new Array(
          'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
          'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
          'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
          'Msxml2.XMLHTTP',
          'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        for (var i = 0; i < msxmlhttp.length; i++) {
          try {
            A = new ActiveXObject(msxmlhttp[i]);
          } catch (e) {
            A = null;
          }
        }

        if (!A && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
          A = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      if (!A)
        sajax_debug("Could not create connection object.");
      return A;
    }

    var sajax_requests = new Array();

    function sajax_cancel() {
      for (var i = 0; i < sajax_requests.length; i++)
        sajax_requests[i].abort();
    }

    function sajax_do_call(func_name, args) {
      var i, x, n;
      var uri;
      var post_data;
      var target_id;
      var charset_html = document.inputEncoding.toLowerCase();
      var charset_esp = [
        "utf-8",
        "windows-1250",
        "windows-1253",
        "windows-1254",
        "windows-1255",
        "windows-1256",
        "windows-1257",
        "iso-8859-4",
        "iso-8859-6",
        "iso-8859-7",
        "iso-8859-8",
        "iso-8859-8-i",
        "iso-8859-9",
        "iso-8859-13",
        "euc-kr"
      ];

      sajax_debug("in sajax_do_call().." + sajax_request_type + "/" + sajax_target_id);
      target_id = sajax_target_id;
      if (typeof(sajax_request_type) == "undefined" || sajax_request_type == "")
        sajax_request_type = "GET";

      uri = "/login/";
      // NM
      if (-1 != uri.indexOf("?"))
        uri = uri.substr(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
      // NM
      if (sajax_request_type == "GET") {

        if (uri.indexOf("?") == -1)
          uri += "?rs=" + escape(func_name);
        else
          uri += "&rs=" + escape(func_name);
        uri += "&rst=" + escape(sajax_target_id);
        uri += "&rsrnd=" + new Date().getTime();

        for (i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++)
          uri += "&rsargs[]=" + escape(args[i]);

        post_data = null;
      } else if (sajax_request_type == "POST") {
        post_data = "rs=" + escape(func_name);
        post_data += "&rst=" + escape(sajax_target_id);
        post_data += "&rsrnd=" + new Date().getTime();

        for (i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++)
          post_data = post_data + "&rsargs[]=" + (-1 != $.inArray(charset_html, charset_esp) ? encodeURIComponent(args[i]) : escape(args[i]));
      } else {
        alert("Illegal request type: " + sajax_request_type);
      }

      x = sajax_init_object();
      if (x == null) {
        if (sajax_failure_redirect != "") {
          location.href = sajax_failure_redirect;
          return false;
        } else {
          sajax_debug("NULL sajax object for user agent:\n" + navigator.userAgent);
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        x.open(sajax_request_type, uri, true);
        // window.open(uri);

        sajax_requests[sajax_requests.length] = x;

        if (sajax_request_type == "POST") {
          x.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1");
          x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }
        //charset magia, acontece aqui
        //x.setCharacterEncoding( document.inputEncoding );
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (x.readyState != 4)
            return;

          sajax_debug("received " + x.responseText);

          var status;
          var data;
          var txt = x.responseText.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
          status = txt.charAt(0);
          data = txt.substring(2);

          if (status == "") {
            // let's just assume this is a pre-response bailout and let it slide for now
          } else if (status == "-")
            alert("Error: " + data);
          else {
            if (target_id != "")
              document.getElementById(target_id).innerHTML = eval(data);
            else {
              try {
                var callback;
                var extra_data = false;
                if (typeof args[args.length - 1] == "object") {
                  callback = args[args.length - 1].callback;
                  extra_data = args[args.length - 1].extra_data;
                } else {
                  callback = args[args.length - 1];
                }
                callback(eval(data), extra_data);
              } catch (e) {
                sajax_debug("Caught error " + e + ": Could not eval " + data);

                if (document.getElementById("id_fatal_error") && data.lastIndexOf('Fatal error') > -1) {
                  sc_ret_error = "<table width=20%><tr><td>" + data + "</td></tr></table>";
                  document.getElementById("id_fatal_error").style.display = "";
                  document.getElementById("id_fatal_error").innerHTML = sc_ret_error;
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      sajax_debug(func_name + " uri = " + uri + "/post = " + post_data);
      x.send(post_data);
      sajax_debug(func_name + " waiting..");
      delete x;
      return true;
    }



    // wrapper for ajax_login_validate_emailid

    function x_ajax_login_validate_emailid() {
      sajax_do_call("ajax_login_validate_emailid",
        x_ajax_login_validate_emailid.arguments);
    }



    // wrapper for ajax_login_validate_passwd

    function x_ajax_login_validate_passwd() {
      sajax_do_call("ajax_login_validate_passwd",
        x_ajax_login_validate_passwd.arguments);
    }
```

Comment: who is we? that you refereing to?

Comment: Where is the DOM of the picture you provided ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help remarking that one cannot simply "Break AJAX" :p

Answer (score 1):

ok - I managed to fix the issues. The main problem was that Apache wasn't running and that was because at some point in the upgrade process I had removed PHP (which I had promptly reinstalled again) and [Plesk doesn't like this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213953465-Apache-fails-to-start-cgi-wrapper-cannot-be-accessed).

The plesk repair tool was very helpful in fixing most of this, but I also needed to hard link

```html
$ ln -s /usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
```

in order to sort out errors within that as well.